# Why does drupal_add_css and drupal_add_html not always work?

Tags: 7, theming

I have a drupal_add_css in my template.php, following a series of drupal_add_html calls.

The drupal_add_html calls, adding meta tags, work except for the first one (regardless of the order I put them in) which is for a meta generator tag, which the jquery form library I'm using requires. I've also tried getting it in by doing the call for markup rather than a tag...same...it doesn't appear.

The drupal_add_css call does not add the css file (I'm not aggregating), even if I specify the full url. If I add the css file to the list in the .info file, it appears, but I only want the file for a specific page, so I'm doing in the pre-render. When the file is not added, there is no reference to it in the page resources or network list as 404. It **does** get referenced in the js behaviors object that Drupal inserts.

Comment: It's a cache perform , css and js are in cache loading , you news to clear caches from databases and then reloading your page ( use drush cc all )

Comment: I clear the cache every time I change the template.php file and push it before running. Like I said...other files that I add appear, so I don't think it's caching. With the css file issue, I'm wondering if there is a limit on the number of css files that I'm hitting. On the meta tag, I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it's a known problem that core provides a generator metatag without an option of replacing or disabling it. The metatag module will do this, or removing it in a custom module via hooking html_head_alter.

I'm not quite certain why drupal_add_css would not work, but adding it with drupal_add_html_head worked.